# I am unable to add this function Image.open( ).convert('RGB') to this code . it says 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'. using google colab

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, python-imaging-library

import keras
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np

def teachable_machine_classification(img, weights_file):
# Load the model
model = keras.models.load_model(weights_file)

```
# Create the array of the right shape to feed into the keras model
data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)
image = img
#image sizing
size = (224, 224)
image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

#turn the image into a numpy array
image_array = np.asarray(image)
# Normalize the image
normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.0) - 1

# Load the image into the array
data[0] = normalized_image_array

# run the inference
prediction = model.predict(data)
return np.argmax(prediction) # return position of the highest probability
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do you maybe try to open an already opened image?
PIL.Image.open(path) takes a file name or path. If I try to open another image, I get the same error message.

```
image_path = r"images\path_to_image.png"
image  = PIL.Image.open(image_path)
image2 = PIL.Image.open(image).convert("RGB")

AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Line two works perfectly fine, line three produces the error since the image, you try to open, is type 'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile'.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).